# How do I create a curved line or filled circle or generally a circle using C++/SDL?

Tags: c++, pixel

Hello I've been trying for ages to make a pixel circle using the putpixel function provided by SDL main website here is that function :

```
void putpixel(int x,int y , int color , SDL_Surface* surface)
{
    unsigned int *ptr = static_cast <unsigned int *> (surface->pixels);

    int offset = y * (surface->pitch/sizeof(unsigned int));

    ptr[offset + x] = color;
}
```

and my question is how do I curve a line or create an circle arc of pixels or any other curved shape then a rectangle or singular pixel or line.

for example here are some pictures

filled pixel circle below
[enter link description here](http://alienryderflex.com/sub_pixel/sub_pixel_antialiasing_2a.gif)

now my idea was too

change the x and y value of the pixel position using + and -  to create the curves but in practice didn't provide the correct results

what my results are in this is to be able to create a circle that is made out of pixels only nothing else.

thank you for anyone who takes the time to read this question

thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

To draw a circle one pixel at at time, you can do something like this

```
int centrex=100,centrey=100;// centre of circle in pixel coords
int radius=50;

float two_pi=6.283f;

float angle_inc=1.0f/radius;
for(float angle=0.0f; angle<= two_pi;angle+=angle_inc){
    xpos=centrex+radius*cos(angle);
    ypos=centrey+radius*sin(angle);
    putpixel(x,pos,ypos,surface);
```

}

This method considers a circle like a bicycle wheel and draws a pixel at the end of each spoke.
This is not the most efficient way to draw a circle using pixels (checkout the [midpoint algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm)). But it will get you started.

Comment: I approve this message. Start with something you understand (like what Ken suggests for circles, or y = Ax+B for straight line segments), and then learn the "real" algorithms (e.g. Bresenham)

Answer (score 0):

For curves you can use [Bezier Curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve). The parametric equation is what you are looking for ;)

Using Bezier Curves, you can draw lines too, all you have to do is use the Linear Bezier Curve.

For circles, you can also use parametric equations, and a quick Google returned me this awesome website: [Link!](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordparamcircle.html).

But one can also use something like [Midpoint Circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) for filled circles. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201200/fast-algorithm-for-drawing-filled-circles

Answer (score 0):

Read up on Bresenham's algorithms. First [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) for a line drawing algorithm, and once you understand how that works [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) for the actual circle algorithm.